# Find a PropertyDescriptor recursively using Reflection in Java

Tags: java, reflection, introspection

Is there anyway to find a property descriptor recursively using Java reflection?

Imagine a scenario where a User class has a field called profile, which itself is another class which has the email attribute.

By having the user object, I need to have access to profile.email so the desirable method signature should be something similar to this:

```
public PropertyDescriptor findPropertyDescriptor(Class<?> clazz, String path)
{
    // Code!
}
```

And the call would be something like:

```
findPropertyDescriptor(User.class, "profile.email")
```

I'm also thinking that calls like below should be possible as well:

```
findPropertyDescriptor(User.class, "addresses[2].postCode")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since nobody has come up with a solution, I have to answer my question here.

Thanks to Spring, this has been already implemented:

```
public static <T> PropertyDescriptor getPropertyDescriptor(T rootObject, String path)
{
    BeanWrapperImpl wrapper = new BeanWrapperImpl(rootObject);
    return wrapper.getPropertyDescriptor(path);
}
```

In addition to the requirement, mentioned in the question, it also supports Maps.

Comment: I can't find this exact method (with path). Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Strictly speaking, you aren't solving your own question because you aren't using the Class object but an instance.